# Birthday Reminder using PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to create a **birthday reminder** using postgreSQL that will print the name  of 'Todays Birthday' and 'Upcoming Birthday'.

**table name** is 'emp_personal_info' with **columns** 'emp_id' 'emp_firstname' ' emp_lastname' 'emp_dob'

the format of 'emp_dob is mm/dd/year'

**php code**

```
<?php
  $con = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=ccaeps_db user=postgres password=postgre");
 $today = date("m.d.y");
 $sql = pg_query($con, "SELECT emp_dob, emp_firstname, emp_lastname FROM emp_personal_info WHERE emp_dob = '$today'");
 echo 'Todays is'.$emp_firstname.' '.$emp_lastname.' birthday'; ?>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: So.. What have you tried to do?

Comment: and pls see https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Tip: use current_date (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) and to_char (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html' to convert to mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: date format of the function date is incorrect.. should be `date("m/d/Y")`